# Flash Recovery Area full

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, recovery, rman, oracle-asm

I have oracle 11g that runs on Linux serve.
I have a Flash Recovery Area, I backup my archive logs to another location.

presently I have very little space left in my Flash Recovery Area (FRA) thereby resulting in my archivelog getting filled up quickly and making my DR unable to receive Redo logs.

I wish to free some space in the FRA.
please which of the directories in the FRA Can I touch in order to free some space.

Here is the information of the directories in my FRA
autobackup   3150
archivelog   6962
controlfile  81
datafile     567774
onlinelog    13338

I know  I can't touch the control file.
am new here and afraid to mess things up.

if I can't delete files from any of these directories to free some space, what is my possible alternative of getting some more space in my FRA.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that Oracle manages the FRA space and will delete files if they are no longer needed, to make space.  You can have FRA 90% used, and it's OK.  For example, archive logs may be backed up to tape, but they will remain in the FRA for faster access if the space is not needed by other files.

First - check for reclaimable space with `SELECT * FROM V$RECOVERY_FILE_DEST;`. The `NAME` field will either be a disk path, or an ASM disk group.  If space is reclaimable, then the files should automatically be cleaned up.

Second - check for free space on the device that stores your FRA (`NAME` from `V$RECOVERY_FILE_DEST`).  If you have space, you can increase the amount of space you allow FRA to use (see `DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE`).  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams061.htm#REFRN10235

> DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE specifies (in bytes) the hard limit on the total space to be used by target database recovery files created in the flash recovery area.

More information is needed to know if any of the files can be cleaned up.